# Who do we want to recruit for Server Fault?

Tags: discussion

Who are industry experts that we want to recruit for Server Fault?  These are people who may simply be capable, knowledgeable, and a general benefit to our profession.  They do not necessarily have to be industry celebrities.

Key candidates would be those who are already active in Internet communities, as involving themselves with SF would be a natural progression.

I'm willing to coordinate contacting individuals with the idea of recruiting their participation on the site.  I want to help take Server Fault to the next level.  The question is who will these people be?

Again, this topic is prompted from [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).

Answer (score 2):

Who will these people be? I don't know but what I do know is that if they do not already know about SF they may not be worth contacting. By now I would expect any active professional in our field to have come across the site at least several times while researching various matters.

If and when they decide to join us they will. If they don't care to participate why do you feel the need to chase them down? Leave them be. What you are proposing is as offensive to me as being called up in the evening by some call center trying to sell me something.

Comment: I think you are overestimating how far Server Fault has proliferated.  More professionals than not I speak to are unaware of it and I think the average skill level demonstrated on the site speaks to this as well.  I am sorry that you are offended, as that was certainly not my intent.

Answer (score 2):

I know where the [SUSE experts](http://forums.opensuse.org/) [lurk](http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/suse-linux-enterprise-server-sles/),  but convincing them to also come here will be tricky. The one thing that might do it is having a spot to talk Sysadminly things with not as much end-usery things, on a site with better traffic.

Comment: as long as they're *aware* of it, I think that's the goal -- whether they like it or not isn't really up to us. Awareness is where it's at.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with John Gardeniers.

I think there's been a similar question before where I talked about how I think things should grow 'naturally'. I can only repeat that - you can't force a site like this to grow in a sustainable manner imho.

If I wasn't already here I would object strongly to being 'bugged' on other forums to join up... it's the best way to make me determined never to join a site, in fact.

Comment: I think you're confusing the methods with spam.  It is more analogous to networking.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest amount of professionals in the field i am aware of use freenode.net and they probably have heard of SF atleast most of the them i am sure ... but yet i am sure more than half of them dont plan to move here and would still prefer to stay hidden in the irc channels.

Sorry that this is unrelated to the question, but i belive the freenode irc network would be a nice place to gather some good professionals...

Comment: Totally a good idea.  I'd mentioned SF to some people on a channel there a couple months ago, they seemed to be interested.  Could you do the same in channels you participate in when the opportunity arises?

Comment: unhappyly it seems from my attempts only people that were still learning or looking for help came thru ehehe ... but i will keep tryingto some extent.